# symfony/flex contains a Composer plugin which is blocked by your allow-plug ins config

Tags: php, symfony, composer-php

I tried run: composer global require "symfony/flex" --prefer-dist --no-progress --no-suggest --classmap-authoritative;   composer clear-cache
and I have this error:

```
#13 0.494 Package operations: 1 install, 0 updates, 0 removals
#13 0.494   - Downloading symfony/flex (v2.2.2)
#13 5.977 
#13 5.985 In PluginManager.php line 762:
#13 5.985                                                                                
#13 5.985   symfony/flex contains a Composer plugin which is blocked by your allow-plug  
#13 5.985   ins config. You may add it to the list if you consider it safe.              
#13 5.985   You can run "composer config --no-plugins allow-plugins.symfony/flex [true|  
#13 5.985   false]" to enable it (true) or disable it explicitly and suppress this exce  
#13 5.985   ption (false)                                                                
#13 5.985   See https://getcomposer.org/allow-plugins                                    
#13 5.985
```

My composer.json looks like this:

```
"config": {
        "allow-plugins": {
            "composer/package-versions-deprecated": true,
            "symfony/flex": true,
            "symfony/runtime": true
        },
        "optimize-autoloader": true,
        "preferred-install": {
            "*": "dist"
        },
        "sort-packages": true
    },
```

I tried reinstall packages but not works.

Comment: What composer version you are using? Check [here](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/discussions/44793)

Comment: It's a version 2.3.5

Comment: so, do you think i should change the composer version? it's strange but I didn't have such a problem before, it just showed up today.

Comment: Sorry, it was 2.3.8 :) I changed to 2.3.5 and it works. Thanks for help